# Update typed object in CosmosDB

Tags: asp.net-core, replace, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I want to update an document in CosmosDB, for this matter, I first retrieve the document and transform it to a typed object, like this:

```
public async Task<T> ReadRawAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var query = _client
        .CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_uri)
        .Where(predicate)
        .AsDocumentQuery();

    var results = new List<T>();
    while (query.HasMoreResults)
        results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());

    return results.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

After some transformations I want to update (replace) that document:

```
await _client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(_uri, document);
```

I am not completely sure this can be done in this way. Could you please point to what is required to do such an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReplaceDocumentAsync` will work only if the `document` has a property named `id` (notice the lower case, it needs to serialize to lowercase id, so you might need a JsonProperty("id")) and a document with this id must exist in the collection.

Also if your collection is partitioned then you need to provide the next object in this method which is the `RequestOptions` and add the PartitionKey value of this document in it.

Comment: my document doesn't have any "id" property on it, it is my idea to completely decouple the typed object with the document in the cosmosdb storage.

Comment: Is your collection partitioned?

Comment: it's not partitioned.

Comment: Then if you try `ReplaceDocumentAsync` your should be getting a `DocumentClientException` saying that the content is invalid because the required properties `id` are missing. Is that correct?

Comment: you are completely right, if not used the ID, there is no way to use this methof

Comment: The way i got around that in [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) was to convert the `document` to `dynamic` and just add the `id` by doing `document.id = documentId` before the action. Assuming you generate the `_uri` by using the `UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri` method which is required for this action then you already have the `documentid` because it is a parameter for the `CreateDocumentUri` method.